# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, sql

```
$thread_id = (isset($_GET['id']));
$thread_id = intval($_GET['id']);

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM threads WHERE id = $thread_id");
```

Can't you use two functions on one variable?? As you can see I check if its set but it still gives me:

*Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\bfhq\thread.php on line 7*

Comment: Some time ago I proposed an setor() language construct to PHP to solve this common problem.  Sadly it was morphed int the new ?: syntax, which does not solve the E_NOTICE problem.  Oh well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of *["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)*

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$thread_id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
```

Which reads as "if `$_GET['id']` is set, set `$thread_id` to `intval($_GET['id'])`, if not, set to 0"

Answer (score 3):

isset() returns a boolean value: TRUE / FALSE. If you want to determine whether $_GET["id"] is set, you need to do so in an IF-Statement, or via a ternary operator.

```
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
  $thread_id = $_GET["id"]; // Bad idea taking values in from $_GET directly
} else {
  die("Thread id not set");
}
```

Comment: Calling intval() on a $_GET value is perfectly reasonable if you expect the variable to be an ID.

Comment: You're right, Paolo. Sorry for the hasty statement on my behalf - I'm just very sensitive when I see $_GET and a query that close ;)

Comment: Only keep in mind that a php integer may have a different min/max values than mysql's numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

This error is dependent on error/warning level set in php.ini.  Its good practice to use...

```
array_key_exists('id', $_GET);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

also: make sure you sanitize that input from the $_GET before you do that.  You're leaving yourself open to mysql injection.

Comment: can mysql injections bypass intval()? doesnt intval allow only numbers.

cheers

Comment: ah, yes i suppose so.  had to make sure intval didn't return false on an error, leaving you with "WHERE = ".  however, the fact that it returns 0 on error could be a problem if you do have records with an id of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of all notices by simply using [error_reporting(4);](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Another, maybe crude but working, method to suppress the notice and sanitize the variable could be:

```
$thread_id = (int)@$_GET["id"];
```

If you do a lot of these things, you maybe want to take a look at [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/filter_var) and put all the functionality into a separate function (eg. get_int("id")).